# Select data from child parent relationship of the same table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, recursive-query

I have below table schema:

```
create table location_master (id serial,name character varying,parent_id integer);

INSERT INTO location_master (name,parent_id)
VALUES
   ('Bombay',1)
 , ('Ahmedabad',1)
 , ('Surat',1)
 , ('Vapi',3)
 , ('Navarangpura',2);
```

[image: location_master]

From above table I want to find the path from source `id = 1` to destination `id = 4`. So the expected result is as below:

[image: Expected outcome]

Here destination `id = 4`.  Which has `parent_id = 3`. On words `id = 3` has `parent_id = 1` and so on.

Example:
A user wants to send a parcel from `id = 1` to `id = 4`. Routing path for the parcel is decided by this table. When a user selects source `id = 1` and destination `id = 4` then the query automatically finds the route from child-parent relationship. Parcel will go through `1,3,4` path.

I tried SELF JOIN for this but did not get the expected result.

Comment: I edit my question. let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: You'll need a recursive query (tag added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thanks joop. I search for Recursive Query and got the solution as I want:

    WITH RECURSIVE demo AS (
    SELECT parent_id      
    FROM location_master                   
    WHERE id = <destination_id>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.parent_id               
    FROM location_master a                 
    JOIN demo b ON(a.id = b.parent_id))
    SELECT DISTINCT location_master.* FROM location_master JOIN demo 
           on location_master.id = demo.parent_id WHERE demo.parent_id != 0 
    UNION 
    SELECT location_master.* FROM location_master WHERE id = <destination_id> 
    ORDER BY id  ;
```